# Add a row of data according to value in specific cell - copy whole row of data below, changing 1 cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

would like to copy and insert a row below the original row, according to 2 specific values in column B.
But, change column B cell's value on the inserted row, for each specific value from original row.
Is there a way to do this with a VB or macro? Thank you in advance

Original column B values FIRE_STEP_UP and FMLA_APPROVED_LEAVE
New Column B values WRK and SICK
See attached.[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51xF2.jpg)   [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shFu4.jpg)

Comment: Loop through column B, preferably from bottom to top, and based on cell value, insert and copy row, and change value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, something like this can be used:

```VB
Sub CopyAndReplace()
Dim i As Long
For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "FIRE_STEP_UP" Then
        Rows(i).Copy
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "WRK"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 2).Value = "FMLA_APPROVED_LEAVE" Then
        Rows(i).Copy
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "SICK"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This loops column `A` from the last used cell up to the first row. Copies, inserts and changes the value in column `B` accordingly.